# Access VBA - Compare an Array to a Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, compare, ms-access-2010

So I think I can set up a key/value pair dictionary in access vba.

That is the first part of this thing I want to do.

```
Dim dict as Object 'Declare the Dictionary object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Create the Dictionary

Dim key, val
key = "SomeKey": val = "SomeValue"
'Add item to VBA Dictionary
If Not dict.Exists(key) Then 
    dict.Add key, val
End If
```

What I need to do next, is take all selected items from a listbox, and make an array.  Then I want to loop through that array, and for each item in the array, check the keys in the dictionary. If there is a match, I will add that key's value to a new array.  Once I have the new array, I will sort it and make it unique, and then I can go from there, to use that array of "needed values"

Does this make sense?

I can explain in more detail, but I doubt it will be necessary as this should be able to be applied in a pretty universal way.

Anyone who can help me with how to write this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you

---

### EDIT

I have worked through all the code to do what I am trying.  My last remaining issue, is that I can't get my final SQL string (Mysql) to run properly, as a record source, for a subform control's source object.  In the below code, I put a comment with "'XXX THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS" to denote where the issue is.  The below code compiles a few things:
list of fields to select
list of views to join to the From statement, with a left join *** (this is the issue)
list of criteria
list of fields to group by

I have been doing a debug.print mysql and it runs in SSMS.  It's valid SQL.  But Access wants all those stupid parentheses when there are multiple joins.  That will complicate this even more, as i will need to know how many parentheses I need to add to the strFrom part of the sql concatenation string.  Here's the code.  The strfrom is where I compile the constant From string with as many Left Join (s) as I need, based on what is run at the time:

```
Private Sub cmdSummary_Click()
    Dim Mysql As String
    Dim strFields As String
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim lbo As ListBox
    Dim itm
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim selFieldsViewList As String
    Dim selFieldsView() As String
    Dim selFieldsViewU() As String
    Dim FView As String
    Dim selCriteriaViews() As String
    Dim AllViewsJoin() As String


'DETERMINE ANY CRITERIA LISTBOXES WITH SELECTIONS, SO CORRESPONDING VIEW CAN BE ADDED TO FROM/JOIN

    selCriteriaViews = BYOR_ConCriteriaViews()

'Debug.Print "selCriteriaViews:"
'Debug.Print Join(selCriteriaViews, vbCrLf)

    strQuery = "Qry_AnyStandardQuery"

'GATHER SUMMARY FIELDS FOR SELECT AND GROUP BY
    Set lbo = Me.lstFields
    If Me.lstFields.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You have not chosen any fields." & vbCrLf & _
        "Attempting to run a report with all fields will be too much!" & vbCrLf & _
        "Please select the summary fields you would like in your report, and run again." & vbCrLf & _
        "Thank you!", vbCritical, "Must Select Fields for Report"
Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each itm In lbo.ItemsSelected
'CREATE , LIST OF FIELDS FOR SELECT AND GROUP BY OF FINAL SQL
            FView = DLookup("sqlView", "tblBYOR_ConFieldViews", "FieldName = '" & lbo.ItemData(itm) & "'")
            strFields = strFields & "[" & FView & "].[" & lbo.ItemData(itm) & "], "
'ADD VALUES TO ARRAY OF SELECTED FIELDS FOR IDENTIFYING VIEWS TO INCLUDE IN FINAL SQL
            FView = DLookup("sqlView", "tblBYOR_ConFieldViews", "FieldName = '" & lbo.ItemData(itm) & "'")
            selFieldsViewList = selFieldsViewList & "," & FView
        Next
        strFields = Left(strFields, Len(strFields) - 2)
        selFieldsView = Split(mid(selFieldsViewList, 2), ",")
    End If

'Debug.Print "selFieldsView:"
'Debug.Print Join(selFieldsView, vbCrLf)
'Debug.Print "selCriteriaViews:"
'Debug.Print Join(selCriteriaViews, vbCrLf)

    AllViewsJoin = Split(Join(selFieldsView, ",") & "," & Join(selCriteriaViews, ","), ",")
'Debug.Print "AllViewsJoin:"
'Debug.Print Join(AllViewsJoin, vbCrLf)

'MAKE VIEW ARRAY UNIQUE, SO WE ONLY JOIN IT ONCE
    selFieldsViewU() = UArray(AllViewsJoin())

'Debug.Print "selFieldsViewU:"
'Debug.Print Join(selFieldsViewU, vbCrLf)

'BUILD THE FROM/JOIN SECTION OF THE SQL
    strFrom = " FROM vw_BYOR_CMCIDs"
'XXX THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS - I HAVE TO DEAL WITH THE JOIN PARENTHESES THAT ACCESS REQUIRES, BECAUSE IT CAN'T TAKE STANDARD SQL
'GRRRR XXX

    For x = LBound(selFieldsViewU) To UBound(selFieldsViewU)
        Select Case selFieldsViewU(x)
            Case "vw_BYOR_ConView1"
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.CID = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".CID "
            Case "vw_BYOR_ConView3"
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.CID = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".CID "
            Case "vw_BYOR_ConView8"
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.MID = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".MID "
            Case Else
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.FKMC = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".FKMC "
        End Select
    Next x

'Debug.Print "final strFrom" & vbCrLf & strFrom

'BUILD THE CRITERIA FOR THE SQL, BASED ON ALL LISTBOX FILTER OPTIONS CHOSEN, IF ANY
    strCriteria = "1=1 "
    strCriteria = strCriteria & _
        "BLAH BLAH BLAH"

'CREATE THE FINAL SQL, BY CONTATENTATING THE SELECTED FIELDS, THE FROM/JOIN, THE CRITERIA, AND GROUPING BY SELECTED FIELDS
    Mysql = "SELECT " & vbCrLf & strFields & vbCrLf & strFrom & vbCrLf & " WHERE " & vbCrLf & strCriteria & vbCrLf & " GROUP BY " & vbCrLf & strFields
    Debug.Print Mysql
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQuery).SQL = Mysql
    Me.frmReports_BYOR_SubformQRY.SourceObject = "QUERY." & strQuery
    Me.frmReports_BYOR_SubformQRY.Visible = True
End Sub
```

If anyone has any thoughts on how to track the count of joins, add the beginning parens ( to the From string, between From and the main query, and then a closing parens ) after each join.  Just not sure how to do that, on the fly, at that point in the code.

Thank you.

Comment: There isn't a dedicated function for this. You need to loop on your array and check each item for `dict.Exists(...)`

Comment: thanks. I think I am going to avoid the dictionary all together.  I made a table of the limited key/value pairs, so I can just loop through the array and do a dlookup to that table. My remaining challenge is when I'm adding items to an array, only add it if the item isn't already in the array, so I don't get dupes.

Comment: FWIW, you can use a dictionary as your *final* array. Put your values as keys and finally get the `dict.keys` as an array of unique values.

Comment: That's what I was looking into, but I was struggling to find the right syntax, for what I need to do.  I am filling an array, and now working on looping through it, so I can do a dlookup, find the view I need to add to my from/join statement, and then continue. 1 part is I want to only add an item to an array, if it's not already in there. The next part is, I made the array as Dim selFields() As String, and then I loop through selected items in a list box, and add the items to the loop as selFields(i) = lbo.Column(0, i). I need that syntax to only do that if it isn't in there, and then loop it

Comment: If you post a skeleton code where you fill your array of values without the uniqueness constraint, it will be easy to help modify it to use a dictionary so that the values are unique.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out all that (been working all morning).  Now I'm fighting with Access being a PITA, when I have to include multiple joins in the dynamic sql statement.  I have to use all these darn parenthesis, which makes the SQL string I have working, not work because I'm running it in access.  So frustrating!

Comment: I updated my original post, with the code I now have.  1 last challenge, and I should have my solution!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it all working.  Even though someone voted down my original post, I found it helpful to talk out my questions in the comments.  I thought I would post my final solution here.  This is a set up of the following:
a dynamic build your own report form in Access.
list boxes for filtering, the report
1 listbox for selecting the fields to go into the report, and a subform control, which will be set to a query. The query will be set to the sql that is dynamically generated, based on the report form's listbox choices made, on the fly.

If anyone wants the public functions called with in this code, which is on-click to run the report, comment and I will post it for you.

```
Private Sub cmdSummary_Click()
    Dim Mysql As String
    Dim strFields As String
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim lbo As ListBox
    Dim itm
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim selFieldsViewList As String
    Dim selFieldsView() As String
    Dim selFieldsViewU() As String
    Dim FView As String
    Dim selCriteriaViews() As String
    Dim AllViewsJoin() As String


'DETERMINE ANY CRITERIA LISTBOXES WITH SELECTIONS, SO CORRESPONDING VIEW CAN BE ADDED TO FROM/JOIN

    selCriteriaViews = BYOR_ConCriteriaViews()

'Debug.Print "selCriteriaViews:"
'Debug.Print Join(selCriteriaViews, vbCrLf)

    strQuery = "Qry_AnyStandardQuery"

'GATHER SUMMARY FIELDS FOR SELECT AND GROUP BY
    Set lbo = Me.lstFields
    If Me.lstFields.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You have not chosen any fields." & vbCrLf & _
        "Attempting to run a report with all fields will be too much!" & vbCrLf & _
        "Please select the summary fields you would like in your report, and run again." & vbCrLf & _
        "Thank you!", vbCritical, "Must Select Fields for Report"
Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each itm In lbo.ItemsSelected
'CREATE , LIST OF FIELDS FOR SELECT AND GROUP BY OF FINAL SQL
            FView = DLookup("sqlView", "tblBYOR_ConFieldViews", "FieldName = '" & lbo.ItemData(itm) & "'")
            strFields = strFields & "[" & FView & "].[" & lbo.ItemData(itm) & "], "
'ADD VALUES TO ARRAY OF SELECTED FIELDS FOR IDENTIFYING VIEWS TO INCLUDE IN FINAL SQL
            FView = DLookup("sqlView", "tblBYOR_ConFieldViews", "FieldName = '" & lbo.ItemData(itm) & "'")
            selFieldsViewList = selFieldsViewList & "," & FView
        Next
        strFields = Left(strFields, Len(strFields) - 2)
        selFieldsView = Split(mid(selFieldsViewList, 2), ",")
    End If

'Debug.Print "selFieldsView:"
'Debug.Print Join(selFieldsView, vbCrLf)
'Debug.Print "selCriteriaViews:"
'Debug.Print Join(selCriteriaViews, vbCrLf)

    AllViewsJoin = Split(Join(selFieldsView, ",") & "," & Join(selCriteriaViews, ","), ",")
'Debug.Print "AllViewsJoin:"
'Debug.Print Join(AllViewsJoin, vbCrLf)

'MAKE VIEW ARRAY UNIQUE, SO WE ONLY JOIN IT ONCE
    selFieldsViewU() = UArray(AllViewsJoin())

'Debug.Print "selFieldsViewU:"
'Debug.Print Join(selFieldsViewU, vbCrLf)


 'COUNT HOW MANY JOINS, SO THE RIGHT AMOUNT OF OPENING PARENTHESES WILL BE ADDED TO THE FROM CLAUSE
 JoinCount = UBound(selFieldsViewU) + 1
'BUILD THE FROM/JOIN SECTION OF THE SQL
     strFrom = " FROM " & String(JoinCount, "(") & "vw_BYOR_CMCIDs "

    For x = LBound(selFieldsViewU) To UBound(selFieldsViewU)
        Select Case selFieldsViewU(x)
            Case "vw_BYOR_ConView1"
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.CID = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".CID) "
            Case "vw_BYOR_ConView3"
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.CID = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".CID) "
            Case "vw_BYOR_ConView8"
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.MID = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".MID) "
            Case Else
                strFrom = strFrom & " Left Join " & selFieldsViewU(x) & " On vw_BYOR_CMCIDs.FKMC = " & selFieldsViewU(x) & ".FKMC) "
        End Select
    Next x

'Debug.Print "final strFrom" & vbCrLf & strFrom

'BUILD THE CRITERIA FOR THE SQL, BASED ON ALL LISTBOX FILTER OPTIONS CHOSEN, IF ANY
    strCriteria = "1=1 "
    strCriteria = strCriteria & _
        "BLAH BLAH BLAH"

'CREATE THE FINAL SQL, BY CONTATENTATING THE SELECTED FIELDS, THE FROM/JOIN, THE CRITERIA, AND GROUPING BY SELECTED FIELDS
    Mysql = "SELECT " & vbCrLf & strFields & vbCrLf & strFrom & vbCrLf & " WHERE " & vbCrLf & strCriteria & vbCrLf & " GROUP BY " & vbCrLf & strFields
    Debug.Print Mysql
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQuery).SQL = Mysql
    Me.frmReports_BYOR_SubformQRY.SourceObject = "QUERY." & strQuery
    Me.frmReports_BYOR_SubformQRY.Visible = True
End Sub
```